# How to delete a local branch in git?

Tags: git

I want to delete a local branch in Git but this failed:

```
git branch -d <branch_name>
```

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: What's the error message? If there are unmerged commits in the branch, you have to provide the `-D` option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you edit your branch & want to delete it without merging it to your master branch, you have to force delete it with the option `-D` instead of `-d`.

```
git branch -D <branch_name>
```

Comment: For anyone who tries the above and it still doesn't work... make sure you aren't currently in the branch you are trying to delete. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

for more info . hidden deep from online documentation:

- -d is a shortcut for `--delete` , and
- -D is for `--delete --force` .

Answer (score 1):

```
git branch -D <branch_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your command to delete a branch is correct:

```
git branch -d <branch_name>
```

But you may have an error message indicating you need to use [the -D option](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-branch) to force the deletion of the branch:

```
git branch -D <branch_name>
```